# Tool script for GeoJSON to Shapefile

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, shapefile, geojson, code-review

I am creating an ArcMap tool script that takes user input and then takes a GeoJSON file from a specified folder and then opens it in ArcMap as a shapefile. The issue I am running into is that I am struggling to create a piece of code that will convert my GeoJSON file to shapefile without requiring the user to download multiple Python packages.

This is where I am currently

```
from osgeo import gdal, ogr

fileloc = r'filename.geojson'
shpfolder = r'filename.shp'
ogr2ogr.main(['','-f', 'ESRI Shapefile', shpfolder, fileloc])
```

However I am also thinking is there a way to use run QGIS in the background to open the GeoJSON file and export it as a shapefile?   Or potentially using the pyshp module to convert it?

Comment: Have you tried ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro? https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/json-to-features.htm

Comment: I would like to since it seems that is a more modern and smooth workflow, unfortunately the organization I am working for only uses Arcmap...

Comment: you could use the json module (standard library) to dump the json to a list or table that could be fed to an insert cursor..

Comment: I like the idea of using the json module, not too sure what you mean by feeding the list to an insert cursor though

Comment: You could create 'rows' from the json (one for each feature).  Create a new, empty shapefile or gdb and create the fields you need to hold the attributes from the geojson.  Use arcpy.da.insertCursor to insert each row into the shapefile.

Comment: You could structure the rows as lists, so you would have a big list of lists.  A row would be like [field1, field2, geometry] that you parse from the json.

Comment: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-data-access/insertcursor-class.htm  - check out the second example in the code samples

Comment: jbalk the way do described worked minus being able to use the parse functionality, instead I wrote the code to append a master list with each coordinate, thanks for the insight.

Comment: If you solved your question, add an answer explaining how. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer. Tks.